# Prometheus Query calculation and negative values for alerts manager

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm writing an alert rule comparing a new value with old values to get an alert if the result is more than 10%.
Something like that.

`(( increase(old value[10m] offset 10m) - increase(new value[10m]) )/ increase(new value[10m]) ) * 100 > 10`

But I can have negative values, and alert message could have values `NaN` or `Infinity`

How can I mitigate this and get only positive values?